# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException is coming while configuring cloud-sql project?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am integrating a Java appengine application with cloud sql using JDO. However, while running the application on the development server getting the below error. In order to connect with cloud sql we have modified the PMF.java.

**PMF.java**

```
public class PMF{

    private static PersistenceManagerFactory PMF;
    private static final ThreadLocal<PersistenceManager> PER_THREAD_PM = new 
    ThreadLocal<PersistenceManager>();

    private PMF() {}

    public static void initialize() {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap();
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
              SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
          System.err.println("Enviroment " + SystemProperty.environment.value() );
          /*properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName",
              "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");*/
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName",
                  "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL",
              System.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/cloud_sqldatabase"));
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "root");
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "#pass12341992");
         // properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema", "true");
          properties.put("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass", "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
        } else {
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName",
              "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL",
              System.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/cloud_sqldatabase"));
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "root");
          properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "#pass12341992");
          //properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema", "true");
          properties.put("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass", "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
        }


    if (PMF != null) {
        return;
        //throw new IllegalStateException("initialize() already called");
    }     
    PMF = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties,"transactions-optional");
    }

    public static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
        PersistenceManager pm = PER_THREAD_PM.get();
        if (pm == null) {
            pm = getPMF().getPersistenceManager();
            PER_THREAD_PM.set(pm);
        }
        return pm;
    }

    public static void finishRequest() {
        PersistenceManager pm = PER_THREAD_PM.get();
        if (pm != null) {
            PER_THREAD_PM.remove();
            Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
            if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            if(!pm.isClosed()){
                pm.close();
            }
        }
    }


    public static PersistenceManagerFactory getPMF() {
         Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap();
            if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
                  SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
              /*properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName",
                  "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");*/
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName",
                      "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL",
                  System.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/cloud_sqldatabase"));
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "root");
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "#pass12341992");
             // properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema", "true");
              properties.put("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass", "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
            } else {
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName",
                  "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL",
                  System.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/cloud_sqldatabase"));
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "<>");
              properties.put("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "<>");
              //properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema", "true");
              properties.put("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass", "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
            }
        if (PMF == null) {
            PMF = JDOHelper
                    .getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties,"transactions-optional");
        }
        return PMF;
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:263)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1128)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1093)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:960)
    at net.giffy.jdo.PMF.getPMF(PMF.java:107)
    at net.giffy.jdo.PMF.getPersistenceManager(PMF.java:60)
    at net.giffy.service.ApplicationService.getApplication(ApplicationService.java:203)
    at net.giffy.service.EntityService.<init>(EntityService.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:681)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:287)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:251)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.<init>(MappedStoreManager.java:133)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:681)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:476)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:288)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Unable to create transactional datasource for connections due to invalid/insufficient input. Consult the log for details and/or review the settings of "datastore.connectionXXX" properties
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
    ... 90 more

2018-12-24 12:33:28.235:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@30b975ad{/,file:///C:/Users/Infiflex52/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/project_sql/,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\Infiflex52\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\project_sql}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [net.giffy.service.EntityService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory|NestedThrowables:|java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:952)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:917)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:343)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractBackendServers$ServerWrapper.startup(AbstractBackendServers.java:729)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractBackendServers.startupAll(AbstractBackendServers.java:266)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:293)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:395)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:238)
```

Comment: Rupsha you need to give some more details.. and show your code too... and the code and the error logs should be posted as text.. not images.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please take a moment to try the code formatting tool provided in the editor, so that code and logs are formatted in a readable fashion. Thanks! I have made this edit for you on this occasion.

Comment: Okay will look into that.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is being solved by giving the connectionURL as **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/giffy_db**, here giffy_db is my local mysql database which has been made on workbench tool and 3306 is the default port.Also the connectionDriverName **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** has been deprecated so had to change it with the newer version which is **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver** and for which had to add a jar in the classpath which is **spring-boot-starter-2.0.5.RELEASE**